# Find rotation of sphere required such that 3 points form an equilateral (or at least isosceles) triangle

Tags: 3d, rotations, spheres

I'm working on solving a computer vision problem related to face rotation.  I have mappings in 2D space of a face (ibug spec), which you can read about here:
https://ibug.doc.ic.ac.uk/resources/facial-point-annotations/

For the purposes of this problem, we can focus on the corners of the eyes and the bottom of the mouth.  These three points essentially form an isosceles triangle, as a 3D projection to 2D.

My goal is to find the rotation of the head in space.  I am thinking that we can treat the head as a sphere, although perhaps just looking at the three points on a plane is enough.  Not really sure if there's a difference to that consideration...

As a human moves around in 3D space, their head will be rotated away from the camera / view point in 3 possible axes: front to back, left to right, and around z... a tilt.

How can I find these rotations from "center", where the face is looking straight at the camera, and the points form an isosceles triangle.  It may be that for the purposes of the question, finding the equalateral triangle might be better since there would be only 1 answer then (assuming the constraints of human motion of a head on a neck).

Comment: Assuming vertices have sufficient depth, for left-right rotations, one side length of the isoceles will differ from the other side length. You could exploit that.

Comment: Yes.  The only way I know how to approach that would be iterative.  I'm hoping there's a formula that I could take advantage of.  I don't know much about 3D projection math.

Comment: I assume you're trying to solve for yaw, pitch and roll. Roll is easy; just the angle of the eyes from the horizontal. You need a fourth point that is not in the plane of the 'corners of the eyes and the bottom of the mouth', say the tip of the nose, to solve for rotation left to right (yaw). Pitch is harder unless you assume, say, a nominal (standard) ratio between the vertical distance between the eyes to nose and nose to mouth of a head at zero yaw, pitch and roll.